# Spring XD: Pipe chain with split, join and local execution

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-xd

I'd like to achieve the following:

- Given a list of URLs (png images), download the files in parallel processes (split)
- Convert the file format for downloaded files in parallel processes (e.g. png2jpg in.png out.jpg)
- Wait until all files are converted, then fetch all files into a **single location** and do a final operation on them (e.g. create a giant mosaic image from all images)

The image conversion is provided as an example. My processing is actually more complex, but I tried to get the requirement through that I need to split file processings and and that I need to do a final processing on the after a join operation.

I have a basic idea how Spring XD pipes are chained (similar to shell pipes). There is a splitter and an aggregator. My expectation would be that I can pass files as objects to the next pipe.

However, how do binary objects, collections and split / aggregate operations play together in XD?

It would be very helpful for me if you could provide me a working example (for example instead of converting for simplicity trigger a shell task "cat file1 file2 > outputfile").

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Processors#splitter

Answer (score 1):

It "just works".

XD uses [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) under the covers; refer to its documentation about splitters/aggregators.

Spring Integration messages have headers and a payload; the framework knows nothing about the payload; it can be anything you want. Presumably you'll start with a list of URLs, split them, invoke http to get the PNG content for each. Invoke some service to do the conversion and send the results to an aggregator.

The splitter sets up headers (`correlationId`, `sequenceSize`, `sequenceNumber`) on each message. A downstream (default) aggregator uses these headers to re-assemble the results (default release strategy is the aggregated group size matches the `sequenceSize` header). In your case the result will be a `Collection` of images; a final custom processor after the aggregator can transform that list into your final mosaic.

**EDIT:**

```
source | splitter | http-client | processor1 | aggregator | processor2 | file
```

Where:

```
source - generates list of URLs
http-client - fetches the PNGs (binary payloads)
processor1 - convert to JPG
processor2 - create mosaic
```

You need custom code in the source, processor1 and processor2; the rest should just be configuration in the stream definition.

**EDIT2:**

You probably want this to be event-driven, so maybe this would be better:

```
http | json-to-object | splitter | http-client | processor1 | aggregator | processor2 | file
```

and POST your list of URLs as JSON.

If you **do** want a polled source instead, a custom source similar to the trigger source would work...

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="output"
        auto-startup="false" ref="myPojo" method="foo">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="myPojo" class="foo.UrlGenerator" />
```

and have `foo()` return null if there's nothing to process, or the list of URLs.

Comment: Can you provide a tiny example for say generating the source collection?

Comment: There seems no json-to-object. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: There's not currently a standard XD `json-to-object` processor, but it's easy to create one; similar to `object-to-json` but using the `<int:json-to-object-transformer/>` in Spring Integration. [Docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#transformer) - scroll down to JSON.

Comment: No reason to use `json-to-object`. `splitter` can simply accept `--expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.*')"`, if your JSON is an array of URLs, of course...